# CSS is not working in Django app, no clue what is wrong

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I know this is a repeated question, but I am unable to find any answers that would make the static files run for me. I am using Django version: 1.10.5 and python version: 3.4.3...

I have read the official documentation too, no luck in solving my problem...

**The following is my project structure:**

```
myproject4
    /myapp/
        /__pycache__/
        /migrations/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
    /myproject/
        /__pycache__/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    /static/
        /css/
            hpage.css
            robot.css
        /images/
            -- Images --
        /js/
            -- JavaScript Files --
    /template/
        hello.html
    manage.py
```

Here's what all I have tried:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

for my hello.html page, right at the top,

```
<link href="{%static 'css/hpage.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{%static 'css/robot.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

for linking my CSS files in hello.html (it makes use of 2 CSS files).

I have tried `{{ STATIC_URL }}` way of doing the same and the necessary stuffs I am supposed to do too, but found no luck there.

When I use the `<style> </style>` tags, the css works perfectly, but that's not what I am looking for.

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapp',
]

#Other stuffs go here

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.views import hello,user_profile
from myapp import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.hello, name='hello'),
    url(r'^hello/user_profile/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def hello(request):
      return render_to_response('hello.html')

def user_profile(request):
      return render_to_response('user_profile.html')
```

Kindly guide me where I am going wrong...

Thank You in advance :)

**EDIT:** In my **settings.py** file, `DEBUG = False` because I have a file called **404.html** that gives out the error page for me as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I have followed to include CSS to my Django Project:

1. First, I have added in the settings.py:

   ```
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
   ```
2. Second in the urls.py (app folder)"

   ```
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```
3. Copied all CSS files in the Project folder (same level with manage.py)
4. Include/Declare CSS in a template (I included mine in base.html)

   ```
   <head>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}" media="screen" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/main.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}">
   </head>
   ```
5. Run:

   ```
   python manage.py collectstatic
   ```

and reload/restart the browser or delete cache.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes to `urls.py` like bellow. and look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) for your ref.

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    rl(r'^admin/$', admin.site.urls, name='admin'),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.hello, name='hello'),
    url(r'^hello/user_profile/', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: remove `STATIC_ROOT` var form settings.py

Comment: Did that, still unable to get the desired result :(