# HTML not loading CSS in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a problem that my HTML code does not load my css files. The code works if put into the main.html  tag, however as outsourced to the separate css files, not working at all.

Link to the project: https://github.com/Svantevith/Python/tree/master/ToDoList

The overall structure of the folder:
[image]

The head tag of main.html:

```
<head>
    <title>ToDoList App</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link id="sheet-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="light.css"> 

    <!-- Nunito Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

In my django project, the rest of HTML files extend the main.html file, for example the register view:

```
{% extends 'base/main.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="header-bar">
        <h1>Register</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            
            <input style="margin-top: 16px" class="button" type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>

        <p>Already have an account? <a id="plain" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></p>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

What might be the problem?

EDIT:
Solved the problem by adding the base/static/base folder and accessing the css via {% static 'base/file.css' %} as mentioned in the comments and official documentation ;)

Comment: Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS is not working in Django app, no clue what is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537453/css-is-not-working-in-django-app-no-clue-what-is-wrong)

Comment: Instead of editing the solution, accept the answer that solves the problem. If you solve your own problem, write an answer yourself and accept it. Other than that, the question looks nice and clear. Maybe a bit more thorough searching the existing ones for duplicates... (or the documentation) ;-)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling, the answer is actually the comment. I cannot mark it as the best answer unfortunately

Comment: Then you can nudge the commenter to write up an answer, so they can get the credit. Or do what Rayyan Shaikh did: write the answer yourself (mark it community wiki) and then mark it accepted. We don't want to eat up the attention of people answering questions with questions that already have an answer. Closing questions helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to just put the {% load static %} on top of your main.html code

And in the Head section, you should change the link as I did in href.

```
<link id="sheet-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'light.css'%}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `href="light.css"` is the problem here. The system is looking for that file in the main folder that you are in. You have to tell the system to go to the `base` folder in the `template` folder using Jinja syntax. Your link should be

```
<link id="sheet-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static light.css %}">
```